# Code to run when app closes

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've found plenty of examples of writing code that executes when a WPF or Windows Forms app terminates, but not for a UWP app. Is there any special C# method you can override, or an event handler you can use to contain cleanup code?

Here is the WPF code I tried but did not work in my UWP app:

`App.xaml.cs` (without the boilerplate usings and namespace declaration)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        void App_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you cannot log off while this app is running");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SafeShutdownWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SafeShutdownWPF"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             SessionEnding="App_SessionEnding">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I tried to use `Process.Exited`, but VS2015 could not recognize Process inside of `System.Diagnostics`.

Comment: I found a lot of examples on the internet (SessionEnding, Process.Exit, and others, AppDomain.ProcessExit), but they only work for UWP and Windows Forms. Errors appear in VS2015 when I try to use them in my app.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What about `AppDomain.ProcessExit`?  the `Process.Exited` event you refer to is used for launched processes called via `Process` class

Comment: Doh, just saw your other comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For UWP apps, you need to use the `Suspending` event on the `Application` object.  If you used the default project template then you should already have a `OnSuspending` method defined, you just have to fill it. Otherwise, subscribe to the event in the constructor:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

And the method should look like (using a deferral to allow asynchronous programming):

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to get what is causing the suspension, so that I can have code that ONLY executes when the Suspension is caused by a session shutdown?

Comment: @M3579 Not sure what you mean by session shutdown, but in any case, as far as I know there's no way to get additional information on the reason of the app suspension

Comment: By session shutdown, I mean that the user logged off or the system shut down.